# how to get href value with html agility pack?

Tags: c#, html, href

i am trying to download a page contain this :

```
<a href="#"  id="10023" target="_blank" >
</a>
```

i tried this code but it return "#" only . 
i want to access the page code but i can't please help me .

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("http://kish4.com");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("(//div[@class='overview'])[{0:D}]//div[@class='line']", 2));
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("(//div[@class='overview'])[{0:D}]//a[@href]", 2)))
        {

            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            listBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue);

        }
```

this is a pop put window and i can't dig out the url .

Comment: well, if that code return "#" than it works correctly as in your example `href` contains only `#` (`<a href="#"  id="10023" target="_blank" >
</a>`)

Comment: @demo in the web site when i click on the hyperlink ( which has href='#' ) it open new page and i want to access that page . i know it should return '#' but i want to get the content of the page with this hyperlink

Comment: Had to look at the comments to see what you were trying to do, maybe you should make it more clear

Comment: as the href is not specified in the html... obviously its been done via javascript... you will need to dig out the url which it is using in the pop out. and pass that in as your htmldoc load in code.

Comment: @Seabizkit that's exactly my question ! how to dig out url for pop out window ???

Comment: I take it that the pop-out is dynamic, ie the url changes?

Comment: by standards... pop outs are not allowed to hide the url, so you could just capture it once loaded..assuming once off before to just capture url,  but i get the feeling your trying to do something dynamically.